# Numerical "Biases" Computation Issue

Tags: computer-algebra

I discovered this issue last night & can't make sense of it. Numerical biases programming sounds ridiculous but the code is the same, only changing the denominator from 4 to 5 and changing the corresponding values and outputs. Why does the 4 denominator work but the 5 doesn't?

#include 
using namespace std;

double main ()
{
double input;

double value;

int round;

double function;

cout  << "Program will calculate remandor from an INTEGER ÷ 4" << endl;

cout << "Enter the INTEGER value: ";
cin >> input;

value = (input/4);

round = (input/4);

function = (value - round);

if (function==0.0)
{cout << ".0";}

if (function==0.25)
{cout << ".25";}

if (function==0.5)
{cout << ".5";}

if (function==0.75)
{cout << ".75";}

return 0;
}

#include 
using namespace std;

double main ()
{
double input;

double value;

int round;

double function;

cout  << "Program will calculate remandor from an INTEGER ÷ 5" << endl;

cout << "Enter the INTEGER value: ";
cin >> input;

value = (input/5);

round = (input/5);

function = (value - round);

if (function==0.0)
{cout << ".0";}

if (function==0.2)
{cout << ".2";}

if (function==0.4)
{cout << ".4";}

if (function==0.6)
{cout << ".6";}

if (function==0.8)
{cout << ".8";}

return 0;
}

Comment: In floating-point arithmetic you can (more or less) divide precisely by a power of 2, but not by any other number.

Comment: Coding questions and questions that require us to read some C++ code are off-topic here.  I can't understand your question.  I don't know what you mean by "Numerical biases programming", or "the code is the same", or "the 4 denominator work but the 5 doesn't".

Answer (score 0):

**This is an answer to "a solution for remained divided by 5 of a given integer".**

The problem is not with `output= input/5 - int(input/5)`, which is a correct way to get the fractional part of a number (alternatively, `input/5 - floor(input/5)`). The problem is with `output == 0.2`. Comparisons for exact equality of floating-point numbers usually does not work. You need to introduce a tolerance, which is related to the accuracy of the representation. In this case, you should use something like `abs(output - 0.2) ≤ 0.2 * epsilon`, where `epsilon` is a small multiple of the relative machine precision (about `2^-52`).

---

For more informative experiments, you'd better observe the quotient

$$\frac{\text{computed value} - \text{ideal value}}{\text{ideal value}}$$

Comment: "Comparisons for exact equality of floating-point numbers usually does not work" I'd say "Comparisons for exact equality of floating-point numbers often does not work as naively expected". It always works, but numbers that you think ought to be equal often aren't.

Answer (score -1):

Floating-point numbers are stored in the following form (forgetting about some niceties):
$$
1.b_1 \ldots b_m \times 2^x,
$$
where $b_1,\ldots,b_m$ are bits, and $x$ is an integer belonging to some bounded range. (You need special encodings to store zero, infinities, NaNs, and so on.)

Dividing a floating-point number by 4 is exact, since it just involves decreasing $x$ by 2 (unless you get underflow, but this won't happen in your case). In contrast, dividing by 5 isn't exact, since 5 isn't a power of 2.  Similarly, whereas 0.25 can be stored exactly in floating-point, 0.2 cannot. The outcome is the kind of behavior that you see.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I now know there are limitations to floating point functions. Very helpful, anyone like to share a solution for remained divided by 5 of a given integer?

Comment: Part of the mystery remains: why does the representation of 0.2 differ from that of 1./5. ?

Comment: 1.0 / 5.0 is not calculated at any point. What is calculated with input = 101 for example is 101.0 / 5.0 - 20.0 which is an entirely different calculation.